# Dúvida com Servlet

Tags: java, jsp

Olá, tenho uma dúvida com Servlet's.

Imagine o quadro:

```
raiz /
     / formulario.jsp
     / Servlet
     / retornos / retorno.jsp
```

O formulário envia à Servlet os dados por post ou get!

Após esse envio, usando RequestDispatcher o que ocorre na realidade?

A) retorno.jsp é incluido em formulário.jsp

B) Servlet redirecionado os dados à partir dela para retorno.jsp

C) Servlet inclui retorno.jsp no seu corpo como se estivesse imprimindo um texto?

O que ocorre na realidade?

Comment: Usando RequestDispatcher#include, ou RequestDispatcher#forward?

Comment: RequestDispatcher#forward

Comment: o próprio nome já diz... #forward será redirecionado.. #include será incluido

Comment: @PedroLaini. A), B) ou C) é a alterativa correta?

Comment: veja a resposta

Answer (score 5):

Veja [esse link](http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher-in-servlet) que mostra exemplo das 2 implementações.

A **alternativa correta** para sua pergunta dependerá de qual método do RequestDispatcher você vai usar.

Ele possui dois métodos: **forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)** e **include(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)**

No link citado, ele está implementando uma página de login da seguinte forma:

- Apresenta um formulário com login/senha.
- O usuário digita o usuário e senha e dá submit.
- Se o login/senha estiver incorreto: ele dá um include mostrando a mensagem que o login/senha está incorreto . **include = na mesma tela**
- Se o login/senha estiverem corretos: ele dá um forward para outra tela dizendo "Welcome, fulano!" **forward = outra tela**

Veja também a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) do `RequestDispatcher`